# How to use TOR with Python3 urllib.request.urlopen()?

Tags: python-3.x, tor

I would like to use TOR with Python3 urllib.request.urlopen() but all examples I found use Python2.

https://code.google.com/p/socksipy-branch/

I came across socksipy but I can't get it to work with Python3 even if it states that the branch is compatible.

I think TOR is a socks proxy but Python3 doesn't seem to include any socks library like Python2?

Does anyone have working examples?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use `httplib2` and `socks` package to do HTTP request via a socks proxy.

I was tried a lot to do it with urllib, but using httplib2 is quite easier.

```
import socks
import httplib2

proxy = httplib2.ProxyInfo(proxy_type=socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5,
                           proxy_host='127.0.0.1',
                           proxy_port=9666)
http = httplib2.Http(proxy_info=proxy, timeout=10)
# do requests
headers, message = http.request(url, "GET", body=body, headers=headers)
```

Comment: But I don't have the socks module with Python3. Where did you get it?

Comment: Converting it to python3 is easy, you can use this convert: http://code.google.com/r/msmhrt-httplib2/source/browse/python2/httplib2/socks.py

Answer (score 0):

You have to perform DNS resolution through the socket

```
def getaddrinfo(*args):
  return [(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM, 6, '', (args[0], args[1]))]
socket.getaddrinfo = getaddrinfo
```

Source: [GitHub](https://github.com/PSNAppz/TorBoT/blob/master/Resources%20And%20Samples/torConnectionExample.py)